# Removing certain duplicate rows within a subset

Tags: r, rstudio, duplicates

I have the following data set with these two columns

```
x   y
1   3
1   4
1   5
1   4
1   2
2   6
2   3
2   4
2   4
3   4
3   2
3   4
3   4
3   6
3   2
```

For a given x, I want to remove all duplicate y's. So I would like to remove row 4, 9,12,13,15. I don't want to remove any y=3 row because even though they duplicate, they appear for different values  of x

Answer (score 0):

You could use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[df[, !duplicated(y), by=x]$V1]
#    x y
#1: 1 3
#2: 1 4
#3: 1 5
#4: 1 2
#5: 2 6
#6: 2 3
#7: 2 4
#8: 3 4
#9: 3 2
#10: 3 6
```

Or another options suggested by @David Arenburg, @Arun

```
 setDT(df)[, .SD[!duplicated(y)], by = x]
 unique(setDT(df), by=c("x", "y"))
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(x = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), y = c(3L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 6L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 2L)), .Names = c("x", "y"), class = "data.frame", row.names =
c(NA, -15L))
```

Comment: What if there are many other columns and these were just two somewhere in middle

Comment: `data.table`'s `unique` method has a `by` argument. Please read `?unique`! `unique(setDT(df), by=c("x", "y"))`.

Answer (score 0):

An approach with `ave` and `duplicated`:

```
> subset(dat, !ave(y, x, FUN = duplicated))
   x y
1  1 3
2  1 4
3  1 5
5  1 2
6  2 6
7  2 3
8  2 4
10 3 4
11 3 2
14 3 6
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have only two columns in your data, just do `unique(df)` (as already mentioned).

If you have more than two columns, then you could also try `dplyr`s package `distinct` function in order to explicitly specify `x` and `y`

```
library(dplyr)
distinct(df, x, y)
#    x y
# 1  1 3
# 2  1 4
# 3  1 5
# 4  1 2
# 5  2 6
# 6  2 3
# 7  2 4
# 8  3 4
# 9  3 2
# 10 3 6
```

Answer (score 0):

As I was looking for a similar answer, I realized a way of using duplicated is missing here.
You could simply use the duplicated() function and pass the different columns.
You can do it on as many columns as you want. It will consider the columns in the search for duplicated rows.

```
    df <- data.frame(matrix(data=c(1,2,1,4,1,3,1,4,2,2,2,5,2,4), ncol=2, byrow = T))
> duplicated(df[, c(1,2)])
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE

    toremove <- duplicated(df[, c(1,2)])
    df <- df[!toremove, ]
```

or directly

```
df <- df[!duplicated(df[, c(1,2)]), ]
```

The duplicated() function is really handy.